# Basic (local) HTML not loading Image or js but loading css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-selectors

I've been working with the web for years, but today I started a basic Angular app for something super simple and I'm just using the angular files and a single html file for my base.

Before doing all the angular stuff, I'm basically just getting the skeleton going and I noticed the browser couldn't find the relative path to the app.js file. It can find the .css files, but not the .js.

So I put an image in to test and it can't find that either! Here's my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ecsApp">
    <head>
        <title>Client Services Support | Elite Chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/foundation.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/main.css">
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body ng-view>
        <img src="public/images/clock.jpg">
        TEST

        <script src="app_client/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my folder structure:

```
project 
    > index.html
    > app_client 
        > app.js
    > public 
        > images 
            > clock.jpg
        > stylesheets
            > main.css
```

I can use an absolute path of the image (system path, IE c:\user\blah\folder\project\public\images\clock.jpg) and it will display. But obviously a system path is completely stupid and unacceptable to use.

Any ideas why I cannot do something as simple as display an image? I even put the image in the same location as the `index.html` file a tried `<img src="clock.jpg">` and it still wouldn't display image.

Comment: use browser dev tools network to analyze what url's are being used by browser. Is likely something wrong with your base tag path

Comment: Have you viewed source then click on the js file path and it came up with nothing?

Comment: `<body ng-view>` should be only `<body>` and below you can add `<div ng-view></div>`

Comment: In the dev console it says `file:///C:/app_client/app.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and when I view source code I cannot click the source url for the code/image.

Comment: you need this running on localhost server. Without `<base>` you would get the styles and js loading but you can't use ajax in file protocol to get templates

Comment: It doesn't make sense the `.css` loads but an `<img` doesn't.

Comment: permissions on js and image folder are correct?

Comment: Permissions are set to full control for the files, so should good. Also, if I put full system path, then they work.. but relative paths do not.

Comment: Seems fairly clear that it's an issue with the use of the `<base` tag. By using it, you've set the folder from which relative addresses are based to `C:/`, so naturally, since the css and has already been encountered, it uses the default base folder (c:/??/project). After then, you set the base folder to `C:/` - thus `C:/` + `app_client/app.js` --> `C:/app_client/app.js`. As others have hinted, you should install a server on your machine and access the site via `localhost/` - xampp (formerly WAMPP & LAMPP - win/linux) has always served me well.

Comment: One would suppose that you could also just place the `script` tag above the `base` tag. More on the `<base` tag here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @enhzflep thanks, that's a great start for me. I commented it out and the image displays. So now I have to figure out how to have the `<base` tag and get the rest of the code to work.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the moral of this story is going to be when doing anything more complex than a static HTML site, use a web server of some kind.

If you look at the HTML in the original question, you'll see in the `<head>` section this: `<base href="/">`. When editing the files locally and ***not*** using a web server (e.g. node.js or xampp or whatever you wish) then the base path (url in the browser) is something like

```
file:///C:/Users/person/folder/project/index.html#/
```

and therefore the browser will try to load files after that `<base>` tag based (haha, pun) on the crazy file path. That's why at that point the following is true:

***not working***
`<img src="public/images/clock.jpg">`

***working***
`<img src="file:///C:/Users/person/folder/project/public/images/clock.jpg">`

**Important:**
Now, if I wanted to **fix** this, I could either run a node.js server and toss these files in or upload to the web to test/view the desired output with the *relative* `src` attribute. Otherwise, I'd have to use the system file path.